# Creating an algorithm to find red intensity of the frames of a video using GPUImage

Tags: objective-c, gpuimage

I need to create an algorithm that will essentially take video input from the rear camera of an iPhone for 30 seconds at 15 frames per second (a total of 450 frames). After the 30 second period is over, no more input should be recorded. Finally, the algorithm should take the average red value or intensity of each of the 450 frames, leaving me with 450 red values. Obviously, I'm using GPUImage to do all of this.

Right now, I have something like this:

```
GPUImageVideoCamera *videoCamera = [[GPUImageVideoCamera alloc] initWithSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480 cameraPosition:AVCaptureDevicePositionBack];
videoCamera.outputImageOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;

GPUImageAverageColor *averageColor = [[GPUImageAverageColor alloc] init];
[averageColor setColorAverageProcessingFinishedBlock:^(CGFloat redComponent, CGFloat greenComponent, CGFloat blueComponent, CGFloat alphaComponent, CMTime frameTime)
// retrieve the average color values
 {
     NSLog(@"%f", redComponent); // print the red values
     // [redValues addObject:@(redComponent)]; <-- this is what I would use to put all of the red values in an array
 }];

[videoCamera addTarget:averageColor];
[videoCamera startCameraCapture];
```

The problem I'm having is that I don't know where to set my desired frames per second of the video (15 frames per second), and I'm also unsure of where to specify how long I want my video sample to be (30 seconds). My biggest problem is that the console isn't printing any red values at all, even though the camera should capture video.

How can I address all of three of these problems? Sample code would be highly appreciated.

Comment: The introductory documentation in the [GitHub reposotory](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage) tells you how to use filters in general, and the one you are interested in in particular (give it a block to receive the averages); and also provides instructions to produce the API documentation. If you've read this edit your question to show what you've tried and what didn't work/you didn't understand.

Comment: I just skimmed the GPUImage doc.  It looks like the pipeline for live video is done for you, so you can skip decomposition steps there.  Take @CRD's advice and start with something simple as described in the doc.  The point is, complex things don't get born whole.  They grow up in simpler (tested) pieces.

Comment: @CRD trying that now.

Comment: @CRD I found the block that I have to use [here](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/GPUImage-PitNikola/0.1.6.3/Classes/GPUImageAverageColor.html), but I'm still not sure how to implement the filter, as the introductory documentation isn't very specific.

Comment: @CRD edited with more details added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your setup above is correct, and the remainder is simply logic that needs to be implemented within the callback block. That block will be triggered once per frame, passing in the RGBA component values (as 0.0-1.0 floats).

If you want this to average the red channel values, set up a sum instance variable (initialized at 0.0) and add each new red value to it. You'll also want to set up a counter instance variable to be incremented once per block activation.

To make this run for 30 seconds, and no longer, take a timestamp before you call `-startCameraCapture` in the above and compare it to the current timestamp every time your block is called. Once that exceeds 30 seconds, pause or stop camera capture and process your results. To obtain the average red color, simply divide your red channel sum by the number of frames measured during this period.

Comment: If I perform the red average function you suggest, won't I only be left with a  single red average value for all of the frames combined? I'm trying to find the average red value of **each** frame; is that possible using your framework?

Comment: I ask that because the documentation for GPUImage strongly suggests that the average red value can be taken for each frame in a video, rather than a single total average red value. Also, one last thing, is the R component each of the RGBA component values the average red value for each frame?

Comment: @fi12 - Oh, I misread your third sentence. In that case, don't maintain a running tally, just take each value (which is the average for that frame) and store it in an array. I should note that the camera doesn't always update at a guaranteed framerate (depending on illumination conditions), so you may end up with more or fewer frames in 30 seconds than you expect.

Comment: Thanks for all your help so far. I've just one more thing to ask: the RGBA section of this link states that the float between 0 and 1 is the opacity value, not the average red value (contrary to what you said.) In the example provided in the link above, the red value is shown as being between 0 and 255, while the opacity is between 0 and 1. As such, I was expecting a red value between 0 and 255. Is there any way to convert the float value to an rgb integer between 0 and 255?

Comment: @fi12 - Each component is fed into that block separately, and each component is provided as a CGFloat from 0.0 - 1.0. `redComponent` is the average red value, `alphaComponent` is the average opacity, etc. The link you provided in your deleted comment has nothing to do with the above, so don't worry about that. To convert to the 0 - 255 range, simply multiply the incoming value by 256 (I think, because it should top out at 0.996 with a 0 base, but I could be wrong and you might need to multiply by 255).

Comment: I'm trying to store the red components in an array and currently I'm using this line of code inserted between the two curly brackets of the GPUImageAverageColor block to store the red components in an array: [redValues addObject:@(redComponent)];

Comment: Unfortunately, this seems to make the compiler completely skip over what is in the curly brackets. What's my error? ((To clarify the line of code I inserted, I've added a commented line that is the line of code I would use.)

Comment: I've asked a new question specifically about this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41666622/gpuimageaveragecolor-block-doesnt-execute-code-in-order).